# JavaScript - Can't return value from function with promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am learning promise in JavaScript but I don't understand why my function doesn't return the right value.

This is my function:

```js
function promise() {
  let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return resolve(["a", "random", "array"]);
  });

  p.then((response) => {
    return response;
  }).catch((error) => {
    return error;
  });
}

console.log(promise());
```

If I run the code I get `undefined`.

I think the problem is that the `console.log` is executed before the value of the `.then` is returned.

Can somebody please help me to solve this problem and maybe explain the problem? :)

Thanks for every answer.

Comment: Your `promise` function has no `return` statement.

Comment: @trincot so if I return a value in the .then the return doesn't count for the outer function ?

Comment: @Lucretius but when we are in the callback of p(response) we should break out of the main function don't we ?

Comment: The `return` in the callback function counts for the callback function only. BTW, that `return` executes *after* the main function has already finished.

Comment: @trincot Ah okay thanks :) Yeah i know but how can I solve this problem ? So that the main function returns the value that is resolved in the promise ?

Comment: This is a very common question. You'll have some interesting reading to do via the link in the blue box at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You must `return` the promise `p` from within the `promise` function.
2. You must await the result of the promise returned by the function before you can access its fulfilled value:

```js
function promise() {
  let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return resolve(["a", "random", "array"]);
  });

  p.then((response) => {
    return response;
  }).catch((error) => {
    return error;
  });
  
  // 1. Return the promise from the function:
  return p;
}

// 2. Await the result before using it:
promise().then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

You said you're learning about promises. Async/await makes all of this much easier:

```html
<script type="module">
// Top level await is available in ES modules

async function promise () {
  try {
    return ["a", "random", "array"];
  }
  catch (exception) {
    return exception;
  }
}

const result = await promise();
console.log(result);

</script>
```

Comment: Okay thank you but If i declare a variable where the result should be assigned to i get Promise {<pending>}:  {function promise() {
    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return resolve(["a", "random", "array"]);
    });
  
    p.then((response) => {
      return response;
    }).catch((error) => {
      return error;
    });
    
    // 1. Return the promise from the function:
    return p;
  }
  
  // 2. Await the result before using it:
  var temp = promise().then((result) => {
                return result
             });

console.log(temp)}

Comment: how can I post the right format of the code in an comment ? xD

Comment: @tombiebl Multi-line formatting in a comment is not possible.

Comment: so i can't assign a variable with promise ? BTW thanks for your answers :)

Comment: @tombiebl See the update to my answer for `await`ing a promise and assigning the fulfilled value to a variable. You can read more at these great articles on MDN: [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). Good luck with your learning!

Comment: works ! thank you very much ! I'll check out the Links you commentet ;)